# JQuery: how to change urls of a iframe if I come from http:// to https://

Tags: jquery, url

I've a little question. I wanna change the url of a IFrame if the customer login and has the url prefix https://

So before login the url of the iframe is e.g. http://www.google.de/pictures/iframe.html
and after he logged in the url of the iframe is https://www.google.de/pictures/iframe.html

The differens is only the "https"

Comment: maybe a server side redirect? otherwise do a regex replace on the src string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need JavaScript to do this. All you need is HTML:

```
<iframe src="//www.google.de/pictures/iframe.html" id="ifrm1">
```

See how I omitted the `http:` or `https:` part? That’s a [scheme-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

With this code, the `iframe` will use `http:` or `https:` depending on whatever scheme/protocol the outer document is using.

Comment: > Caveat: When used on a <link> or @import for a stylesheet, IE7 and IE8 download the file twice. All other uses, however, are just fine. So this not working properly yet

Comment: @VMAtm: Sure, but OP’s question is about an HTML document loading inside an iframe, so there’s no problem at all.

Comment: I think this can lead to two requests for the server instead of one. This can't be good :)

Comment: @VMAtm: It will only request the HTML document once per page load. This does exactly what the OP requested. Of course if you load the page over HTTP first and then switch to HTTPS it will have loaded the embedded document from two different locations, but that’s true for any solution to OP’s problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```
<img src="http://yourImage.com/image.gif" id="pct1" />

<script>
    $().ready(function () {
        prefix = parent.location.protocol;
        if (prefix == "http:") {
            // change to http
            $('img#pct1').attr("src", $('img#pct1').attr("src").replace("https://", "http://"));
        }
        else {
            // change to https
            $('img#pct1').attr("src", $('img#pct1').attr("src").replace("http://", "https://"));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why use JavaScript if you can just use HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757727/jquery-how-to-change-urls-of-a-i-frame-if-i-come-from-http-to-https/6757873#6757873

Answer (score 0):

If the image is embedded in your site you should use relative path to the image and switch the site over to https.

Anyway, you can change the image source using jQuery this way.

```
$("#yourImageTagIdOrOtherSelector").attr('src','https://www.google.de/pictures/picture1.jpg');
```